# java over http protocol in Loadrunner

Tags: java, loadrunner

I'm doing performance testing for mobile application which is developed in java language and 
coming to load runner scripting i'm using java over HTTP as protocol.

Actually i'm not aware of this protocol,i can able to record the application but i don't know whether all the requests got captured or not.

Note:In java over HTTP protocol no generation log and no run time viewer to validate the requests .So how can we validate?

Please share your experience on this protocol and get me out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a cross post with several posts on facebook.  If these other posts are yours then please pick one thread as reference for answers

## ShotgunPostsAreSPAM